# Reason for SIGSEGV

Tags: linux, gdb, elf

I have a sample application that I have created to understand an experiment with ELF binary format.

When I run it, it crashes after receiving SIGSEGV.
After attaching it with gdb and then running, I see that it crashes at the following line

```
(gdb) x/i 0x08054697
=> 0x8054697:   mov    %edx,0x80f8f5c
```

But, the destination address of this instruction is a valid address and this memory is mapped as writable.

```
(gdb) p/x *0x80f8f5c
$3 = 0x0
(gdb) si

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08054697 in ?? ()
```

I am trying to understand why does this process receive SIGSEGV? What other things should I look for in order to figure out the reason.

Here is the output of readelf showing regions of virtual memory that are mapped.

```
Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x8048e08
There are 13 program headers, starting at offset 52

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000034 0x08047034 0x08047034 0x002a4 0x002a4 R E 0x1
  INTERP         0x0001d4 0x080471d4 0x080471d4 0x00013 0x00013 R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.2]
  DYNAMIC        0x0001e7 0x080471e7 0x080471e7 0x00060 0x00060 RW  0x1
  LOAD           0x000000 0x08047000 0x08047000 0x01000 0x01000 R E 0x1
  LOAD           0x001000 0x08048000 0x08048000 0xae948 0xae948 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x0b06dc 0x080f86dc 0x080f86dc 0x015f8 0x07730 RW  0x1000
  LOAD           0x0c52b8 0x081002b8 0x081002b8 0x00400 0x00400 R E 0x1
  LOAD           0x0c56b8 0x081006b8 0x081006b8 0x00400 0x00400 R E 0x1
  LOAD           0x0c5ab8 0x08100ab8 0x08100ab8 0x00400 0x00400 R E 0x1
  NOTE           0x0010f4 0x080480f4 0x080480f4 0x00044 0x00044 R   0x4
  TLS            0x0b06dc 0x080f86dc 0x080f86dc 0x00010 0x00030 R   0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x001000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000 RW  0x4
  GNU_RELRO      0x0b06dc 0x080f86dc 0x080f86dc 0x00924 0x00924 R   0x1
```

Relevant instructions from the binary are

```
0x805467d:  mov    0x64(%esp),%edx
0x8054681:  mov    0x68(%esp),%ecx
0x8054685:  mov    %eax,0x80f9a44
0x805468a:  lea    0x4(%ecx,%edx,4),%eax
0x805468e:  mov    0x78(%esp),%edx
0x8054692:  mov    %eax,0x80ff1c8
==> 0x8054697:  mov    %edx,0x80f8f5c
0x805469d:  lea    0x0(%esi),%esi
```

**Is there a way in gdb to figure out if the address is mapped as readonly or not?**

**What could be the reason for this Segmentation fault?**

C Code

---

```
/*

ECHOSERV.C
==========
(c) Paul Griffiths, 1999
Email: mail@paulgriffiths.net

Simple TCP/IP echo server.

*/


#include <sys/socket.h>       /*  socket definitions        */
#include <sys/types.h>        /*  socket types              */
#include <arpa/inet.h>        /*  inet (3) functions         */
#include <unistd.h>           /*  misc. UNIX functions      */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include "helper.h"

#define LOG_FILE "test_disk.txt"

/*  Global constants  */

#define ECHO_PORT          (20002)
#define MAX_LINE           (1000)


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int       list_s;                /*  listening socket          */
    int       conn_s;                /*  connection socket         */
    short int port;                  /*  port number               */
    struct    sockaddr_in servaddr;  /*  socket address structure  */
    char      buffer[MAX_LINE];      /*  character buffer          */
    char     *endptr;                /*  for strtol()              */
    int file_fd = open(LOG_FILE, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT);

    /*  Get port number from the command line, and
        set to default port if no arguments were supplied  */
    if ( argc == 2 ) {
        port = strtol(argv[1], &endptr, 0);
        if ( *endptr ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ECHOSERV: Invalid port number.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    else if ( argc < 2 ) {
        port = ECHO_PORT;
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "ECHOSERV: Invalid arguments.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    /*  Create the listening socket  */

    if ( (list_s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ECHOSERV: Error creating listening socket.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    /*  Set all bytes in socket address structure to
        zero, and fill in the relevant data members   */

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port        = htons(port);


    /*  Bind our socket addresss to the 
        listening socket, and call listen()  */

    if ( bind(list_s, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ECHOSERV: Error calling bind()\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ( listen(list_s, LISTENQ) < 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ECHOSERV: Error calling listen()\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    /*  Enter an infinite loop to respond
        to client requests and echo input  */

    while ( 1 ) {

        /*  Wait for a connection, then accept() it  */

        if ( (conn_s = accept(list_s, NULL, NULL) ) < 0 ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ECHOSERV: Error calling accept()\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }


        /*  Retrieve an input line from the connected socket
            then simply write it back to the same socket.     */

        Readline(conn_s, buffer, MAX_LINE-1);
        Writeline(conn_s, buffer, strlen(buffer));
        Writeline(file_fd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
        printf("%s\n", buffer);

        /*  Close the connected socket  */

        if ( close(conn_s) < 0 ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ECHOSERV: Error calling close()\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}


/*

HELPER.C
========
(c) Paul Griffiths, 1999
Email: mail@paulgriffiths.net

Implementation of sockets helper functions.

Many of these functions are adapted from, inspired by, or 
otherwise shamelessly plagiarised from "Unix Network 
Programming", W Richard Stevens (Prentice Hall).

*/

#include "helper.h"
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>


/*  Read a line from a socket  */

ssize_t Readline(int sockd, void *vptr, size_t maxlen) {
    ssize_t n, rc;
    char    c, *buffer;

    buffer = (char *)vptr;

    for ( n = 1; n < maxlen; n++ ) {

        if ( (rc = read(sockd, &c, 1)) == 1 ) {
            *buffer++ = c;
            if ( c == '\n' )
                break;
        }
        else if ( rc == 0 ) {
            if ( n == 1 )
                return 0;
            else
                break;
        }
        else {
            if ( errno == EINTR )
                continue;
            return -1;
        }
    }

    *buffer = 0;
    return n;
}


/*  Write a line to a socket  */

ssize_t Writeline(int sockd, const void *vptr, size_t n) {
    size_t      nleft;
    ssize_t     nwritten;
    const char *buffer;

    buffer = (const char *)vptr;
    nleft  = n;

    while ( nleft > 0 ) {
        if ( (nwritten = write(sockd, buffer, nleft)) <= 0 ) {
            if ( errno == EINTR )
                nwritten = 0;
            else
                return -1;
        }
        nleft  -= nwritten;
        buffer += nwritten;
    }

    return n;
}
```

Comment: Are you writing this in assembly? Could you please post some code?

Comment: this is probably related to the name of this website :D . You should add some code because because at this stage we can only speculate on this, but i think that i know what your problem is.

Comment: Well, I am attempting to convert a statically linked binary to dynamically link. As a first step, I have added new LOAD segments in the Virtual address space of the binary, and added PT_INTERP, a dummy PT_DYNAMIC segment. The C code is simple TCP echo server.

Comment: implementation != algorithms != your purposes = we need to see some code to answer to your question.

Comment: I have added the C code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But, the destination address of this instruction is a valid address and this memory is mapped as writable.

Not it's **not** (or the instruction wouldn't have caused a `SIGSEGV`).

The destination `0x80f8f5c` is "covered" by this LOAD segment:

```
LOAD           0x0b06dc 0x080f86dc 0x080f86dc 0x015f8 0x07730 RW  0x1000
```

but also by this:

```
GNU_RELRO      0x0b06dc 0x080f86dc 0x080f86dc 0x00924 0x00924 R   0x1
```

the `GNU_RELRO` asks the runtime loader to make this part of address space read-only after the loader has performed the relocation (which is exactly what it did, and what triggered your crash).

> Is there a way in gdb to figure out if the address is mapped as readonly or not?

You can ask gdb with `info proc map`, or just look in `/proc/<pid>/maps`. Either way you'll discover that the memory is mapped read-only.